# Integrating Langevin Dynamics equations in computer simulation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations, stochastic-processes, molecular-dynamics

In a Langevin Dynamics simulation the following equation is solved numerically :
$$
 m_i\frac{d^2r_i}{dt^2}=F_{int}-\gamma\frac{dr_i}{dt}+R(t)$$

$$\langle R(t)\rangle=0 \quad \quad \langle R(t)R(t')\rangle=\sqrt{2k_BT\gamma m_i}\delta(t-t') $$
Where, $T$ is the target temperature of the simulation.
Can this equation be integrated by using Velocity-Verlet scheme ? I have seen in the literature that there are many integrators which have been specifically developed to integrate this equation of motion.
To cite two examples :
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cplett.2006.07.086,  https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4802990.
Are there any restrictions in using ordinary integrators like Velocity-Verlet, leapfrog, Predictor-corrector which are normally used to integrate ordinary differential equations ?

Comment: This is an ordinary linear differential equation with constant coefficients - that is, it is exactly solvable in terms of the unknown random function $R(t)$. As a tip, I suggest solving first the equation for velocity, $v_i=\frac{d r_i}{dt}$.

Comment: I didn't properly understand your point. In the equation there is a force due to interaction among the particles $F_{int}$( say, coloumb interaction in case of charged particles). If we consider this force to be zero, the resulting eqation can be solved analytically. Are you suggesting that ?

Comment: @RogerVadim no it's not, $R(t)$ is stochastic, which means that this is an SDE, not an ODE.

Comment: @KyleKanos yes, but it can be formally solved, to produce all the desired correlation functions of positiona nd velocity in terms of noise correlation function.

Comment: If the force is position-dependent, then indeed it is not exactly solvable. Perhaps, you could expand your post to explain more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RogerVadim Why presence of position dependent forces makes in unsolvable exactly ? Is it so that if i have velocity dependent force it is analytically solvable like lorentz force ?

Comment: @RogerVadim OP's query isn't "how does one solve this SDE?" but "how does one solve this SDE using numerical methods?" (second sentence after equation + last sentence overall).

Comment: if the force is position dependent, $F=F(r)$, then unless $F(r)=kr$ the DOE is nonlinear in the position variable.

Comment: Can someone explain to me how asking whether a numerical scheme is useful for one diff eq is a homework question? This question is basically equivalent to the [first two items on the *what types of comp-phys questions we can answer*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/computational-physics/info) in the tag info...

Answer (score 4):

Because the $R$ term is [stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process), there isn't "a" solution you obtain when numerically integrating this; you actually need to integrate the system a multitude of times for many different paths in order to generate a distribution of possible paths to time $t$. So the focus for solving SDEs is on the stochastic component, finding ways to stabilize integrations/solutions depending on the form of the coefficients (e.g., constants, dependent on $x$, etc).
The other methods you mention, verlet & predictor-corrector, have different focuses that are important to ODEs; for instance, verlet methods are focused on conserving energy during the evolution.

Given a generic stochastic differential equation (SDE),
$$\mathrm{d}x=\mu\mathrm{d}t+\sigma\mathrm{d}W,$$
you can actually use the simple Euler scheme for SDEs, called the [Euler-Maruyama method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method), which looks very much like the Euler scheme but with a stochastic term, e.g.

```
for path = 1 to num_paths
    dt = 1 / num_steps
    time = 0
    x[0] = 0
    for i = 1 to num_steps
        x[i] = x[i-1] + dt * mu + W(dt) * sigma
        time += dt
    // averaging, plotting, etc..
```

where $W(dt)=\varphi(0, \sqrt{dt})$ is the [random normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with 0 mean and variance $dt$.

Other methods generally include additional terms in the stochastic component, such as the [Milstein method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milstein_method), which replaces the update of `x[i]` in the above as,

```
dW = W(dt)
x[i] = x[i-1] + mu(x,t) * dt + sigma(x,t) * dW 
              + 0.5 * sigma(x,t) * sigma_deriv(x,t) * (dW**2 - dt)
```

where `sigma_deriv` is $\partial_x\sigma$. The [SDE version for the Runge-Kutta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_method_(SDE)) also is similar to the above. If $\sigma$ is a constant, then these two reduce to the Euler-Maruyama method.

Peter Kloeden has a [very good book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540570748) on the subject of numerical SDEs, it might be worth the time investment in studying from it.